# MSSQL - add new column in hierarchical table funcions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three table functions :

**Step 1:**

1. Function **func1** which return one select:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func1] ()
    RETURNS TABLE AS    
    RETURN 
        (
            SELECT
                1 AS col1,
                2 AS col2,
                3 AS col3
        )
    GO
```

1. Function **func2** which return all from func1:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func2] ()
    RETURNS TABLE AS  
    RETURN 
        (
            SELECT * FROM func1()
        )
    GO
```

1. Function **func3** which return the columns from func1 called from func2, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func3] ()
    RETURNS TABLE AS  
    RETURN 
        (
            SELECT 
                col1,
                col2,
                col3
            FROM func2()
        )
    GO
```

The problem become when i add new column in **func1** named **col4** and i try to add the same name of the column in **func3**.

**Step 2:**

1. Alter **func1** to add the new column **col4**:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func1] ()
    RETURNS TABLE AS    
    RETURN 
        (
            SELECT
                1 AS col1,
                2 AS col2,
                3 AS col3,
                4 AS col4, --the new column
        )
    GO
```

1. The **func2** remain the same because is 'select all the columns from func1'.
2. Alter **func3** to add the same column from func1 (**col4**):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func3] ()
    RETURNS TABLE AS  
    RETURN 
        (
            SELECT 
                col1,
                col2,
                col3,
                col4, -- the new column from func1
            FROM func2()
        )
    GO
```

When i run this last query i get this error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure func3, Line 11 Invalid column
>   name 'col4'.

My question is: The MSSQL has some references held in cache?
I try to restart the SQL Server but this solution don't work.

The only way i found is to alter also the func2 with no change and after run the alter of the func3.

Is some other method, or what is the reason?

Comment: There are slight errors in in your sql in step2 col4 should be without comma and use sql comment --

Comment: extra comma after column 4 in func3 and func1

Comment: the comment, i add here not in sql, is not problem from sintax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh the functions so the sql will recompile them

```
EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule 'func2';
```

Otherwise the sql server will only "see" the old version and not detect that there has been changes in func2

MSDN says:

sp_refreshsqlmodule should be run when changes are made to the objects underlying the module that affect its definition. Otherwise, the module might produce unexpected results when it is queried or invoked. [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx)